# Regex to replace only the first occurrence in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

how can I replace items in bulk?
I have a long text and there are some things I would like to replace.
Specifically I have these values:

```
(€ <em>39.20</em>)
(€ <em>167.08</em>)
(€ <em>87.62</em>)
(€ <em>39.20</em>)
(€ <em>87.21</em>)
(€ <em>37.17</em>)
(€ <em>24.42</em>)
(€ <em>102.96</em>)
(€ <em>14.47</em>)
(€ <em>39.20</em>)
(€ <em>263.96</em>)
(€ <em>84.71</em>)
(€ <em>84.71</em>)
(€ <em>50.65</em>)
(€ <em>62.71</em>)
(€ <em>121.92</em>)
(€ <em>121.92</em>)
(€ <em>120.69</em>)
(€ <em>18.73</em>)
(€ <em>165.38</em>)
```

how can I replace only the first element so as not to invalidate everything if they have equal values?
Because I will replace each element with a new one. So the substitution must be element by single element as it was initially imposed.

I had tried with this but it doesn't work because it replaces me all right away and therefore it no longer works with the subsequent elements:

FIND:

```
(€ <em>39.20</em>)|(€ <em>84.71</em>)|(€ <em>18.73</em>)
```

REPLACE:

```
(?1€ <em>XXXXX</em>) (?2€ <em>YYYYY</em>) (?3€ <em>ZZZZZZ</em>)
```

in this way, however, it replaces ALL elements 39.20 and ALL 87.71.
While I want it to replace ONLY THE FIRST item 39.20 it finds and ONLY FIRST 87.71.
How can I do?

Comment: Can you just click "Replace" instead of "Replace all"?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work on Notepad++ (because I don't have it) but **you could turn off the global flag of your RegEx**. Or is it that you can't change the flags. Because if you turn off the global flag, it'll stop once it finds the first item matching the expression

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do such job with 1 step regex process. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.